# Pool Garbage Collection Strategy

Tags: c++, memory-management, garbage-collection, pool

I'n my application I'm using pools to speed up allocation of certain types of resources:

e.g.

```
tbb::concurrent_unordered_map<size_t, tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue<resource>> pools;

std::shared_ptr<resource> create_resource(size_t size)
{
    auto pool = pools[size];

    std::shared_ptr<resource> resource;
    if(!pool->try_pop(resource))    
        resource.reset(new resource(size)); 

    return std::shared_ptr<host_buffer>(resource.get(), [=](resource*)
    {
        pool->push(resource);
    });
}
```

This works well, however I'm having some issues with high memory usage.

If the usage of resources changes in my application I have a lot of pre-allocated resources that are not needed and only taking memory space.

I would need some kind of strategy which would allow me somehow to detect when a certain pooled resource is not expected to be allocated again and dynamically adapt the pools, e.g. if a pool has not had a size less than 2 for more than a second then one resource is released.

Does anyone have any suggestions in regards to what strategies can be used to minimize memory usage while still keeping most the extra performance of pooling resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by keeping statistics of pool usage and flush it every second.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution: define the size of your queues as 2^N (N must be at least 2), when the pool gets bigger than 2^N, you increase N in one unity, when the queue is smaller than 2^(N-2), you decrease the N in one unity.

It is a very lightweight idea that may be used in many cases.

Comment: That doesn't work unless he can rearrange the internal data, which you probably can't with pools.

Comment: Yeah, that's a limitation. But you can make your resources rearrangeable using pointers.

Comment: Also, I just realized this DOES apply to the internal queues.  My bad.

Comment: Sounds like a good and simple way, however its a bit sub-optimal when the resource size is high and the amount of resources is low.